# SQL: Subquery returned more than a single value

Tags: sql

```
select emailId
from <table1>
where <cloumn1> in (select <column1>
                    from <table2>
                    where <condition1> and <condition2> and <condition3> is null
                   )
                  ) as <alias Name>
```

In sql database, I have 2 emailID associated with a role in table2. Now, while fetching, I need both the emailIDs, along with the other fields. 
How to modify the above query so that I don't get "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error.
PS: this query will be a subquery.

Comment: apparently, this is just some part of the whole query, and not the one giving you that error message

Comment: The query that you have provided should return an error on the second `)`.  The subquery is fine, because it is an `in` query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think that op is using this whole query as a column on another `SELECT`

Comment: This sub query is throwing the error, if i remove it the entire query works fine.

Comment: you are not posting the whole query, though

Comment: Which database engine do you use? (MySQL,MSSQL,Oracle,PostgreSQL)?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.emailId, *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.column1 = t1.column1
WHERE t2.condition = something
```

You can just use an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Add `TOP 1` between the `SELECT` keyword and the first column.

Long answer, use JOIN instead as a subquery is very inefficient.

UPDATE:
TOP 1 is only good for MS-SQL, other versions may use different ways to `LIMIT` the result set, but the solution is the same.